# try catch not working in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

if i try to run following code in sql server 2005 i get error

```
BEGIN TRY

        SELECT 1/0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
            ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
            ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
            ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH;
    GO
```

Error:

```
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'TRY'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 7
'ERROR_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.
```

i was using sql server 2000 service manager but now i have installed sql server 2005 service manager but still get the error..one  article related to it says

**the reason for a such error is seems to be the target database is running on a MS SQL Server 2000 server. So be sure that your database server is SQL2005**

what does it mean..?what changes i have to do???

Comment: @ken...try catch is not present in sql server 2000 so thats not my question...my try catch is not working in sql server 2005 itself i hope u r clear now...thanx

Comment: @ken..in the very beginning itself i hv specified i m writing this code in sql server 2005..i hope u noticed that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be using SQL Server 2005 or above to be able to use TRY...CATCH, installing SQL Server Management Studio will not help if you are still connecting to a SQL 2000 server.

Answer (score 0):

**the reason for a such error is seems to be the target database is running on a MS SQL Server 2000 server. So be sure that your database server is SQL2005**

Comment: @Mike C.: You didn't notice the other people who had already answered with the same info?

Comment: I was pointing out that he answered his own question in the original post.

Comment: @Mike: So did the rest of us. @anay seems determined to not listen to the answers, though.