# SQL Server 2000 compatible script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

this T-SQL script works fine in SQL Server 2005 but in SQL Server 2000 it says incorrect Syntax near 'Try' 'End'. Any help please?

```
Begin Transaction 
Begin Try 
  UPDATE Test 
  SET RefID = 'bc27de13-2323-4ce8-8c87-0171efbd812a' 
  WHERE RefID = 'bc27de13-2323-4ce8-8c87-0171ffbd812a'; 

  DELETE FROM Physician 
  WHERE RefID = 'bc27de13-2323-4ce8-8c87-0171ffbd812a' 

  Commit Transaction 
End Try 
Begin Catch 
  Rollback Transaction 
End Catch
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810032/try-catch-not-working-in-sql-server-2005/1810201#1810201

check this question it is similiar to your question

Comment: Why are you developing in SQL Server 2005 if the database you are writing code for is a SQL Server 2000 database? You whould never have this problem if you develop against the correct database. All you have done is waste your companies time writing code that has no possibility of working.

Answer (score 4):

As Sikender said in his comment, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810032/try-catch-not-working-in-sql-server-2005/1810201#1810201) post asks almost exactly the same question, and the answer here is the same. SQL Server 2000 doesn't suport try..catch; that was added in SQL Server 2005. So no matter what you try, it will **never** work in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ken White told `try and catch` is not supported in SQL server 2000. you can use `@@ERROR` for your purpose. you can check it after every statement and if an error is occurred do the rollback.
You can use following code:

```
Begin Transaction 
  UPDATE Test 
  SET RefID = 'bc27de13-2323-4ce8-8c87-0171efbd812a' 
  WHERE RefID = 'bc27de13-2323-4ce8-8c87-0171ffbd812a'; 
   if @@ERROR<>0
      Rollback transaction
  DELETE FROM Physician 
  WHERE RefID = 'bc27de13-2323-4ce8-8c87-0171ffbd812a' 
      if @@ERROR<>0
          Rollback transaction
  Commit Transaction
```